# Parse html using php

Tags: php

I am able to parse another page using DOM. I am able to retrieve **hrefs**, **imgs** and so

on. How should i b able to parse this?

```
  <span class="abc up" id="price">+9395</span>
```

Comment: what do you want to get out of it?

Comment: Is it in an HTML document, or by itself?  We need to see a sample case.  Do you identify it by it's class or id?

Comment: it is a separate html doc... which i return to my page..(I do an ajax post from my page).. identifying in either ways would be fine..

Comment: phpQuery ftw. http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the DOMElement, you get the value by accessing the nodeValue property... Example below:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<span class="abc up" id="price">+9395</span>  ');

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');

echo $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I assumed you had found the node already... As Alistair says you could use XPath.

http://de.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$spans = $xpath->query('//span[@id="price"]');
echo $spans->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

To determine the Xpath you can use various modern browsers and look for a unique path to the desired element.

Comment: @Jacob: What if there are many **spans** ...??? Is it possible to do a combination of, say: -- getElementsBy(TagName or Class) and getElementById ???

Comment: @Jacob: **Ori's** seems to be a one-liner... simple

Comment: I thought you were looking within a larger document for a specific span and extracting the value.

Comment: `strip_tags` will work on a string. You don't have a string, you have a document.

Comment: but what if i open the file and assign it to a handle and then use it in --strip_tags-- ...???

Comment: It will give you every bit of text in the file... So you will get the title appended to every other bit of text, and somewhere in there will be the value you want, but now impossible to distinguish.

Comment: $html = str_get_html("URL");

$node = $html->find("change");

echo $node->plaintext; I get N ERROR

Comment: Looks like you're using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net. First look at the documentation shows if you are loading a URL use `file_get_html($url)`

Comment: i sue file_get.... i refer to the element id as: $html->find("#change")... but returns **Array**

Comment: $html->find('#change', 0); returns the first one.

Answer (score 1):

For nontrivial parsing of HTML (or XML), you'll need something that can intelligently traverse the DOM, like DOMDocument or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/), or XPath, etc. However, for very trivial cases—and this appears to be one—you can simply use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
echo strip_tags('<span class="abc up" id="price">+9395</span>');
```

Produces `+9395`.

Comment: that was gr8... simple and perfect

Comment: Trivial cases because the strings you are passing to `strip_tags` must contain nothing but the value you want for this to work. If, for example, you pass it `<span>+9395</span><p>some other data</p>` it'll return `+9395some other data`, which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it using XPath too:

```
<?php
$html = '<span class="abc up" id="price">+9395</span>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$results = $xpath->query('//span');

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

That will show all values for the span elements. If you wanted to search by id you'd use //span[@id="price"] and by class //span[@class="abc up"]

Comment: What if there are many spans ...??? Is it possible to do a combination of, say: -- getElementsBy(TagName or Class) and getElementById ??

Answer (score 0):

use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
//turn the html into a dom object:
$html = str_get_html('<span class="abc up" id="price">+9395</span>');

//find the first element with id "price":
$node->find('#price', 0);

//grab its inner text:
echo $node->innertext;
```

it uses css3 style selectors, which is nice